# android TextView customization

Tags: android, text, textview, customization

I want to know how to design a TextView and use it in the app?
For example, the number of the followers, following and tweets in the twitter.
They are all designed and use as a TextView.
Any solution?!

Comment: you need custom the style and text ?

Comment: It sounds like you are new to Android. You should start by reading the developer docs http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html. These are a great resource and can help you understand Android as a whole.

Comment: will I asked because i didn't actually understand what I can customize because I can customize a button but I don't know what it can be on the textview . what I mean can i customize in photoshop and use it as a textview ?!

Comment: A TextView can have a background image, so, yes, you can use PhotoShop to make a background for a TextView.

Comment: with customization you mean change the font?

Comment: no not the font only the design of the textview .so how can i use the designed textview in android ?